# Mouse wheel scroll events persist after hitting meta key

Tags: touchpad, mouse-scroll

For awhile now (including in Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04), I've experienced an issue with scroll events initiated on my Touchpad. Steps to reproduce are:
1) Open Firefox
2) Start a vertical scroll event on Touchpad (two-finger scroll, in my case)
3) Quickly hit ctrl

The results are that Firefox will start zooming in or zooming out the page. I also experience this if I start a scroll event and quickly switch to a different workspace -- where my Terminal will start scrolling up or down. I would expect that the scroll event would die as soon a meta key is hit.

I'm on a Thinkpad W510 on Ubuntu 11.04 using Unity. Here's all the info I can find on my Touchpad:
[   10.808053] Synaptics Touchpad, model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd047b3/0xb40000/0xa0000
[   10.863551] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events and keyboard events are independent.  In addition, the mouse wheel triggers multiple events, not a single event with a range.  You can think of this like a physical mousewheel that has click stops.  Each stop is a single event.  This is why a keyboard key does not cancel a mouse event and why continuing to scroll on your trackpad fires multiple events.

Comment: In that case, can the scroll event end when I lift my fingers off of the Touchpad?