# Delayed touchpad scroll event causes crazy zooming if top of the page is reached

Tags: 14.04, unity, touchpad, scrolling

I have been experiencing this issue for years and that is quite annoying :)

If I scroll down using "two finger" touchpad gesture, the scroll itself takes effect immediately. But if I'm on the top of the page and I (occasionally) scroll up and then (within 2-3 secs after finishing scrolling and releasing the touchpad) press `Ctrl`, system interprets these two events (scroll and ctrl) as a single `Scroll+Ctrl` event as and starts zooming everything crazy, even though these events are not overlapping (and even have 2-3 seconds between them).

Typical scenario: I'm scrolling a page, hit the top of the page, wait a little (1-3 sec), then press Ctr-Tab and together with switching the tab, I also get both of my tabs content zoomed crazily (typically ~700% in chrome). And that's somewhat annoying, because you have to 1) wait until chrome re-renders it with a new scale 2) press `Ctrl-0` 3) wait until in re-renders it again with a default scale :)

An interesting detail is that I do not observe this behavior in any application if scroll event was successfully "dispatched as a scroll": if I'm not hitting the top of the page yet, and scroll up, and press `Ctrl` immediately - no zooming takes place (as if - as soon as it is not the top of the page - this "scroll" was successfully "eaten"="dispatched" by the target app and removed from event queue).

System and UI themselves run super-smoothly so it's definitely not an event-handling lag.

This guy describes similar experiance here: [Mouse wheel scroll events persist after hitting meta key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41889/mouse-wheel-scroll-events-persist-after-hitting-meta-key)

Or there might be a tweak for Unity that disables zooming scroll behavior at all? (like this: [How to disable ctrl + scroll zoom in Lubuntu or openbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644959/how-to-disable-ctrl-scroll-zoom-in-lubuntu-or-openbox) )

Ubuntu 14.04.4

Acer Aspire V5-171

Graphics: Intel HD 4000 (out-of-box drivers)

Comment: This is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253697). Please star it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I'm not the only one [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465965/advanced-inertial-scrolling-configuration?rq=1)[[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565705/adding-a-threshold-to-two-finger-scrolling-on-touchpad?rq=1) concerned with that issue and that is a Xor bug.

The only workaround I found which kind of works is [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-mousewheel-zoom/ckhlfagjncfmdieecfekjbpnnaekhlhd/reviews) for chrome.

**UPD** Extension does not seem to work properly with last version of chrome, but doing `synclient CoastingSpeed=0` seems to handle everything perfectly for me without any negative side effects.